# How can SQL trigger logic be represented in Entity Framework code, so that it is visible, testable, etc.?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

A few colleagues and I are working with a database with several dozen triggers, performing a variety of operations (on the same table, on other tables, for auditing...). How can we pull this into the main codebase, so that the pre-operation logic is preserved, yet, the code is searchable, testable, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use should use a SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) project for that, it puts your entire schema and all SQL scripts under source control, and even has a Unit Testing framework/feature.

Comment: Since we're using EF, a coworker has suggested overriding SaveChanges, for inter-table dependent operations. Since we have several different dbcontexts, this seems like it could work. Does this make sense?

Comment: As long as you are 100% sure that is the only way you Wil ever access the data (so no)